# Transaction too large

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang

I have an instruction which has a heavy payload, And I am getting `Transaction too large` Error, I wanted to know if there is a way to handle this error or should I break the transaction into two pieces?

The instruction is:

```
pub fn save_tournament_eight_players(
ctx: Context<SaveTournamentEightPlayers>,
games: [Game; 7],
prize: u8,
entry_fee: u8,
players: [Pubkey; 8],
winner: Pubkey,
time_stamp: String,
) -> Result<()> {
let tournament = &mut ctx.accounts.tournament;

tournament.games = games;
tournament.prize = prize;
tournament.entry_fee = entry_fee;
tournament.players = players;
tournament.winner = winner;

msg!("User Added");

Ok(())
}
```

Each `Game` size is 118 bytes.

Comment: Hello Reza, share your repository and I will be happy to help you and solve your doubt

Answer (score 1):

You don't really get a lot of bytes to play around with in the transaction, 1280 bytes, so if you're trying to pass in 7 game objects, each 118 bytes and 8 pubkeys, each 32 bytes, then you probably shouldn't do that! A more sensible approach would be to store as much data as you can inside an account and load the data from that account instead of from the transaction instruction data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't get the part you said "Store as much data as you can inside an account and load the data from that account", because in my case I am inserting data into the account via the instruction.
How about cutting the parameters and calling the instruction multiple times?

Comment: This is really more of a design question. Imo a more standard way to design this would be to upload all the data you need for your functions to a given set of accounts and then when you need to access the data you load up those accounts. It's just a different way of looking at the problem. Rather than viewing it as a one time thing to upload a ton of data in your transactions in one go.

Comment: You are right about that but In your solution, you would load all the data all the time afterward, but in my solution, it is gathered together once at the begging and avoids complexity and more data accounts linking.
Am i wrong?