# Access violation in stack frame

Tags: anchor

I am facing an error called `Access violation in stack frame ...`, I tried to solve my problem with [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-to-investigate-access-violation-errors) but didn't work.

My instruction :

```
pub fn save_tournament_eight_players(
ctx: Context<SaveTournamentEightPlayers>,
prize: u8,
entry_fee: u8,
players: [Pubkey; 8],
winner: Pubkey,
time_stamp: String,
) -> Result<()> {
....
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction( prize: u8,
entry_fee: u8,
players: [Pubkey; 8],
winner: Pubkey,
time_stamp: String,)]
pub struct SaveTournamentEightPlayers<'info> {
#[account(init, payer = authority,seeds = [time_stamp.as_bytes(),players[0].key().as_ref(),],bump , space = TournamentEightPlayers::MAX_SIZE  + 8)]
pub tournament: Box<Account<'info, TournamentEightPlayers>>,
#[account(mut)]
pub authority: Signer<'info>,
pub system_program: Program<'info , System>,
pub clock: Sysvar<'info , Clock>
}
```

My struct with `games` property which deleting it will solve the problem.

```
#[account]
pub struct TournamentEightPlayers {
pub games: [Game; 7],          // 118 * 7
pub prize: u8,           // 1
pub entry_fee: u8,        // 1
pub players: [Pubkey; 8],       // 32 * 8
pub winner: Pubkey,            // 32
}

impl TournamentEightPlayers {
pub const MAX_SIZE: usize = 8 + 826 + 1 + 1 + 256 + 32;
  }
```

Full error message on the console:

```
ConfirmError: Raw transaction 2Xj3BmoMfixYf5aPFeJMgwws45WUwcp2oAdWK9KUgXDjLs1NUVTgo59dkt1fBf1bsnh7F1kfoq9QooTPTHPTskDP failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"ProgramFailedToComplete"]}})
```

Full error message on program logs:

```
Transaction executed in slot 6:
Signature: 2Xj3BmoMfixYf5aPFeJMgwws45WUwcp2oAdWK9KUgXDjLs1NUVTgo59dkt1fBf1bsnh7F1kfoq9QooTPTHPTskDP
Status: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
Log Messages:
  Program CMg9XnvkrAC51jZZ7LRjQcLRcyJd4LkLMnALH4w4m8SX invoke [1]
  Program log: Instruction: SaveTournamentEightPlayers
  Program CMg9XnvkrAC51jZZ7LRjQcLRcyJd4LkLMnALH4w4m8SX consumed 2375 of 200000 compute units
  Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005e40 of size 8 by instruction #5630
  Program CMg9XnvkrAC51jZZ7LRjQcLRcyJd4LkLMnALH4w4m8SX failed: Program failed to complete
```

Comment: Kindly include the full error message.

Comment: Definitely, updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you're putting to much data onto the stack. Try <box>ing accounts or reducing the amount of data on accounts, or switch to using a `zero_copy` approach which means the variables don't get loaded onto the stack automatically.

Comment: I have seen people making data accounts larger than 1KB, How can they do that?

Comment: `zero copy` which means the variables don't get loaded onto the stack automatically

Comment: Henry E thanks for the answer and please update the answer with the `zero copy` approach so that I can choose the final answer.

Comment: Sorry but you'll have to look up the details of how to use `zero_copy` for yourself

Comment: Yeah, I have solved the problem, I have used the zero_copy approach.
I just wanted to have the right answer in the Answer section.
And by the why I don't know why but the pointer(box) approach didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you wanted a full example of the `zero_copy` approach. Updated the answer. Not sure why box doesn't work sometimes. It's linked to something in the anchor internals.

Comment: Thanks for the update, The `box` approach did not work for me, and it might work if I try it now because I had transaction too large error that I was getting which was like this error too, and we have been talking about it recently: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/transaction-too-large/3821?noredirect=1#comment3399_3821