Solana 1.18 CLI Stack explosion
There is definitely an issue with programs built via solana 1.18 having their stacks exploded.
This is not a duplicate question. This is specifically asking why version 1.18 compilation has lead larger stack usage.
"Access violation in stack frame...".
I keep having to go back to 1.17 to build my programs so that they actually work.
I don't know enough about the CLI to know what could be causing this.

What exact version of the CLI are you using?

See: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/access-violation-in-stack-frame
